# Is it possible to login in Unity when the nomodeset parameter is set?

Tags: 11.04, unity, kernel

I need to set the nomodeset parameter when booting from grub to make the new kernel 2.6.38 work. The first time I did it I got a message stating that for some kind of limitation I couldn't login with Unity, I suppose it was related to this parameter.

If I boot with the 2.6.35 everything is working perfectly (nomodeset needs not to be set), and Unity is OK. Is it somehow possible to login with Unity even if the nomodeset parameter is set?

Thanks!

Comment: Please file a bug for your system indicating you need nomodeset as a parameter.  We want to find all systems affected by this on Natty.

Comment: Already filed a bugreport and 2.6.39 is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume, in conclusion, that it is not possible to login in Unity when nomodeset parameter is set. If anyone else had any more complete information, please answer and I'll check that as correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just set it at boot like you did and it will show you that error and drop you into Classic Desktop. From there install your Graphics Driver and reboot.

Try [Problem: Need to fully remove -fglrx and reinstall -ati from scratch](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/FglrxInteferesWithRadeonDriver#Problem%3a%20%20Need%20to%20fully%20remove%20-fglrx%20and%20reinstall%20-ati%20from%20scratch)

Comment: My graphics driver? I already have my graphics driver installed... I have an ATI and so I ha installed xserver-xorg-video-ati, xserver-xorg-video-radeon etc... Isn't this sufficient?

Comment: Rename xorg.conf and reboot. sudo mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.bak

Comment: I don't have any xorg.conf there. I only have many xorg.conf.*. Which one? All of them?

Comment: Already gone through that link and did everything. Nothing changed. The proprietary drivers are not installed, just the opensource ATI drivers are.

Comment: @Extender: What do you mean? I can't understand... I do have open drivers... I would like to know if it is possible to run Unity with that parameter set, because my system seems to require it for 2.6.38.